# io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: Invalid protobuf byte sequence

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, grpc-java

I'm attempting to deploy the code to an AWS server, and while the build is successful, the deployment fails with the following error:

io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: Invalid protobuf byte sequence

Note: The appplication is up and running in the local.

I need help on fixing this one

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.